# ocaml: what is an expression that has the keyword val in parenthesis?

Tags: ocaml

I ran into this piece of code here and I don't understand the syntax:

```ml
module Proof = (val p)
```

I know `val` can be used in a module type or a signature, but I haven't seen it being used this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This syntax is used for *unpacking* first class modules.

```ml
module type IntWrapper = sig
  val wrappedInt : int
end

module MyIntWrapper : IntWrapper = struct
  let wrappedInt = 2
end

(* pack a module into a value *)
let packedModule = (module MyIntWrapper : IntWrapper)

(* unpack module *)
module UnpackedModule = (val packedModule : IntWrapper)

(* or *)
module UnpackedModule' : IntWrapper = (val packedModule)
```

Reference: [Real world ocaml book](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/first-class-modules.html)